# Lyx underbrace is broken

Tags: lyx

While using underbrace in Lyx, the result looks really bad. [image]

The left to are done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> option, with `\underbrace{Earth}_{E}` (or similar), and the right three are `\overset{\underbrace{Comparison\, to}}{I}` or similar.

As you can see, the brace is broken. How can I fix this?

Comment: This *is* a rendering issue with the viewer. You will see that this disappears when you zoom in/out. That is, at specific zoom levels it appears "broken", while at others it seems fine.

Comment: Also, you should include [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) in your document preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble, add `\usepackage{amsmath}`) and use `\underbrace{\text{Earth}}_{S}` instead.

Comment: amsmath is there, and this remains in ALL zoom levels, in both evince, and okular

Comment: I'm sure it won't happen with [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/). I can't test it now but will later using LyX.

Comment: okey, thank you, but what to do in a linux machine?

Comment: Try the Linux variant of Adobe Reader please.

Comment: The emphasis on a *viewer* issue means that you're not doing anything wrong, and there's actually nothing you can do to fix it. Sure you can use a viewer that shows it nicely for *you*, but someone else might only have a viewer that doesn't render the output properly. Braces like these are [built up of smaller pieces to allow for any kind of stretching](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109701/5764).

Comment: Adobe Reader view at [100%](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX7aj.png), [150%](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B5hCg.png), [200%](http://i.stack.imgur.com/idJwH.png).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the comments.

Just in case anyone actually is still looking for sorting the issue in LINUX, i am still answering the question myself - please let me know if this is inappropriate:

Removing amsmath, and using txfonts sets the fonts to URW, i love it. BUT TXFONT would cause some characters to go mad, e.g. in mathmode, the character S followed by E would cause a nasty space between S and E. pxfont would solve this. Do not also forget to add mathtools, if you plan to use under- and overbrace /under- and overset.

This solves the issue with Okular.