# Vertical alignment using cases

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, cases

Using the following code, one gets the `$X$` vertically aligned with the "center" of the cases. Is there a way to vertically align the `$X$` with the `$0$` in this output?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    X=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how should looks the curly brace?

Comment: @Zarko: It wouldn´t be symmetric. The pointy part would be towards the upper side in front of the equal sign.

Comment: This is can be only drawn with `tikz` or `pstrick` packages ... and as all answer says: don't doing this, result is ugly.

Comment: @Zarko: When one has many cases and this is at the beginning of a question (in an exam say), having the equal sign centered is uglier, because it looks like the brace invades the previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but the result is very dubious.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
X=\begin{array}[t]\{{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}.
  0, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
  1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
X=\begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
  1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>* Big understatement; actually I believe it is completely wrong. Making the brace asymmetric would be even worse. See [A curly brace with an asymmetric cusp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226155/a-curly-brace-with-an-asymmetric-cusp) for this, I refuse to even think about it. `;-)`</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the link @egreg, that´s closer to what I want, whether it´s popular or not :)

Answer (score 3):

Since `cases` is basically a `matrix` environment, a `\begin{matrix} X\\ \end{matrix}` should align this entry.

But it does **not** look nice! Don't do this!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{matrix} X = \\
      \\
      \end{matrix}  
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}


  \begin{equation}
    \begin{matrix} X  \\
      \\
    \end{matrix}  =
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian, the first alternative would look good if the pointy part of the brace was also aligned with the equal sign. Is this possible?

Comment: @RamirodelaVega: Huh??? The `pointy` part of the brace is centered -- it can't be centered any longer if you want to force that to be aligned with the `=` as well and the `0` as well.

Comment: I guess the brace would need to be different, it would not have the "pointy part" in the center.

Comment: @RamirodelaVega: That's what I said -- it's asymmetric. No, that's not nice

Answer (score 3):

It looks nicer with a bracket. Here is a simple way to do it with the `empheq` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

  \begin{empheq}[left ={\begin{gathered}X=\\ ~\end{gathered}\empheqlbrack}]{gather} 
\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
       & 0, &\quad & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
       & 1, & & \text{otherwise}
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]