Aligning the tip of a vertical curly brace (around a nicematrix) with surrounding text
Edit:
While A curly brace with an asymmetric cusp has a lot of valuable solutions, none of them are geared to nicematrix. In particular, the tikz solution creates a whole tikzpicture for the object, whereas I'd only like to annotate with tikz. It feels more natural that way, though I'm open to feedback on this philosophy.

In my deployment of this idea, I thought that it might be more aesthetically pleasing if the vertex of the curly brace aligned with the surrounding text. Is there a way to do this? I know its possible in tikz, so maybe there's an analog.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}
\begin{document} 
Text:
$\begin{NiceArray}[t,margin]{l}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        a & b \\
        c & d 
    \end{aligned}
    \CodeAfter\SubMatrix\{{1-1}{1-1}{.}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}



@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good catch! It almost warrants a close vote, but I think that the emphasis on nicematrix, and in particular, \CodeAfter does make it unique. They are after the same visual result, but the middleman is different. What do you think?

Personally, I'd say duplicate. You already know how \CodeAfter works and can use the approaches from the linked answers to solve your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Okay, feel free to close. I do significantly prefer your solution, however. I'm voting to close too.

Already voted to close, let's see what the review queue thinks :)  (using tikz for asymmetrical braces is covered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226157/36296 )

Quick hack using tikz. Adjust the aspect= option to align the tip of the curly brace with your text as needed.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document} 
Text:
$\begin{NiceArray}[t,margin]{ll}
        \mathstrut a & b \\
        \mathstrut c & d 
    \CodeAfter
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[line width=0.8pt,decorate,decoration={brace,aspect=0.75}] ([xshift=-0.2em]2-1.south west) -- ([xshift=-0.2em]1-1.north west);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}



Awesome, thank you! Depending on the horizontal spacing and visual consistency, I might post a follow-up later.

@Jasper You're welcome!

@Jasper It's difficult to see something uglier than this!

@egreg it is possible I might put the aligned inside a node with a brace around it to avoid overlay :-)

@egreg There is always a way to make it uglier: https://i.sstatic.net/HTPZ8pOy.png :P

You can use cases instead of nicematrix
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}
\begin{document} 
Text:$    \begin{cases}
        a & b \\
        c & d 
    \end{cases}
$

\end{document}


Happy New Year 2025

Happy New Year! Is it possible to still preserve the text being top-aligned? That is a specific requirement that I have. Also, good to know about cases!

Do you agree with use of minipage ?

It's possible! let me check. Nevermind, I don't think it solves the curly brace problem.
