# Extensible triple-bracket delimiter with a new symbol

Tags: delimiters, mathtools

`\DeclarePairedDelimiter` allows one to define extensible delimiters (for example using the `\big` option).  An example is provided below with double brackets.  I need a similar delimiter with triple brackets.  As I was unable to find one, I built it from the double bracket symbol found in `stmaryd`.  Unfortunately, I cannot use it with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` :(  So, my question is: How to define a macro for an extensible triple-bracket delimiter?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,stmaryrd}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\dbr}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}

\newcommand{\tbr}[1]{\llbracket\mkern-5mu\llbracket #1 \rrbracket\mkern-5mu\rrbracket}


\begin{document}

Double brackets:
\[
  \dbr{x} \quad \dbr[\big]{T^T}
\]

Triple brackets:
\[
  \tbr{x} \quad \tbr{T^T}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: basically you can't really do it unless you have a font with a triple bracket, but there isn't such a character in Unicode. You could use `\Bigl\llbracket\!\Bigl[` or some such

Comment: A solution could be to build the desired pair of triple brackets by means of a virtual font.

Comment: You can typeset such delimiters with the `nath` package, they are input as `\triple[` and `\triple]`, respectively; note, however, that this package also introduces a different way of writing math formulae in the source, making it superfuous, among other thigs, to use explicit `\left` and `\right` specifiers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Encouraged](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43654672#43654672) by David Carlisle, I eventually resolved to post this answer.  I had begun to write a comprehensive one that explained how the solution works, but I soon realized that it would have largely exceeded the 30000 character limit—indeed, only the code amounts to a total of more than 26000 bytes!  Maybe I’ll post the explanations as a separate answer, for now please refer to:

- [How to create a virtual font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25852);
- [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111802) to
  [How can I create a new extensible symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109699);
- [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255714) to the question
  [Design of new brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253614);
- [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254916) to the question
  [Arbitrary \left \right delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251999).

Solution based on virtual fonts; it provides you with two new extensible symbols named `\lBbrack` and `\rBbrack`, that you can use in exactly the same way (with `\bigl` & Co., `\left`, `\right`, `\genfrac`, `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, …) as any other delimiter.  So, for instance, along the lines of

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Bra}{[}{]}
```

you could similarly say

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\WonderBra}{\lBbrack}{\rBbrack}
```

Instructions for testing the solution:

1. Create a new, empty directory and move to it.
2. Save the following code into `tripledelimiters10.vpl`:

   ```
   (FAMILY TRIPLEDELIMITERS)
   (CODINGSCHEME FONTSPECIFIC)
   (DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
   (COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
   (COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
   (MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME cmex10))
   (MAPFONT D 1 (FONTNAME cmsy10))
   (MAPFONT D 2 (FONTNAME cmr10))
   (FONTDIMEN
     (SLANT R 0.0)
     (SPACE R 0.0)
     (STRETCH R 0.0)
     (SHRINK R 0.0)
     (XHEIGHT R 0.430555)
     (QUAD R 1.000003)
     (EXTRASPACE R 0.0)
     )
   (CHARACTER O 0
     (CHARWD R 0.916672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 20)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 0)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.229168)
       (SETCHAR O 0)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.229168)
       (SETCHAR O 0)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 1
     (CHARWD R 0.916672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 21)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 1)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.229168)
       (SETCHAR O 1)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.229168)
       (SETCHAR O 1)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 2
     (CHARWD R 0.833338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 150)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 2)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2083345)
       (SETCHAR O 2)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2083345)
       (SETCHAR O 2)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 3
     (CHARWD R 0.833338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 151)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 3)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2083345)
       (SETCHAR O 3)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2083345)
       (SETCHAR O 3)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 4
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 152)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 4)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 4)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 4)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 5
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 153)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 5)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 5)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 5)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 6
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 154)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 6)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 6)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 6)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 7
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 155)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 7)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 7)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 7)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 10
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 156)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 10)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 10)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 10)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 11
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 157)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 11)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 11)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 11)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 12
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 104)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 12)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 12)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 12)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 13
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.160013)
     (NEXTLARGER O 105)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 13)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 13)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 13)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 14
     (CHARWD R 0.666668)
     (CHARDP R 0.600006)
     (VARCHAR
       (REP O 14)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 14)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.166667)
       (SETCHAR O 14)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.166667)
       (SETCHAR O 14)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 20
     (CHARWD R 1.194448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 22)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 20)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.298612)
       (SETCHAR O 20)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.298612)
       (SETCHAR O 20)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 21
     (CHARWD R 1.194448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 23)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 21)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.298612)
       (SETCHAR O 21)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.298612)
       (SETCHAR O 21)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 22
     (CHARWD R 1.472229)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 40)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 22)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.36805725)
       (SETCHAR O 22)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.36805725)
       (SETCHAR O 22)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 23
     (CHARWD R 1.472229)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 41)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 23)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.36805725)
       (SETCHAR O 23)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.36805725)
       (SETCHAR O 23)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 24
     (CHARWD R 1.055562)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 42)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 24)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 24)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 24)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 25
     (CHARWD R 1.055562)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 43)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 25)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 25)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 25)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 26
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 44)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 26)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 26)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 26)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 27
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 45)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 27)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 27)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 27)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 30
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 46)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 30)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 30)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 30)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 31
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 47)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 31)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 31)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 31)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 32
     (CHARWD R 1.500004)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 50)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 32)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 32)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 32)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 33
     (CHARWD R 1.500004)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 51)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 33)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 33)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 33)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 34
     (CHARWD R 1.500004)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 52)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 34)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 34)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 34)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 35
     (CHARWD R 1.500004)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.360025)
     (NEXTLARGER O 53)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 35)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 35)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.375001)
       (SETCHAR O 35)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 40
     (CHARWD R 1.58334)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 60)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 40)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.395835)
       (SETCHAR O 40)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.395835)
       (SETCHAR O 40)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 41
     (CHARWD R 1.58334)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 61)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 41)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.395835)
       (SETCHAR O 41)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.395835)
       (SETCHAR O 41)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 42
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 62)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 42)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 42)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 42)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 43
     (CHARWD R 1.166672)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 63)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 43)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 43)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.291668)
       (SETCHAR O 43)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 44
     (CHARWD R 1.277782)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 64)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 44)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 44)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 44)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 45
     (CHARWD R 1.277782)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 65)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 45)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 45)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 45)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 46
     (CHARWD R 1.277782)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 66)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 46)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 46)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 46)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 47
     (CHARWD R 1.277782)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 67)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 47)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 47)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3194455)
       (SETCHAR O 47)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 50
     (CHARWD R 1.61112)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 70)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 50)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 50)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 50)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 51
     (CHARWD R 1.61112)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (NEXTLARGER O 71)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 51)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 51)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 51)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 52
     (CHARWD R 1.61112)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 52)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 52)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 52)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 53
     (CHARWD R 1.61112)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 2.9600315)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 53)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 53)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.40278)
       (SETCHAR O 53)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 60
     (CHARWD R 1.750006)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 60)
       (BOT O 100)
       (REP O 102)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 60)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 60)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 60)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 61
     (CHARWD R 1.750006)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 61)
       (BOT O 101)
       (REP O 103)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 61)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 61)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 61)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 62
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 62)
       (BOT O 64)
       (REP O 66)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 62)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 62)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 62)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 63
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 63)
       (BOT O 65)
       (REP O 67)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 63)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 63)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 63)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 64
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (BOT O 64)
       (REP O 66)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 64)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 64)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 64)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 65
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (BOT O 65)
       (REP O 67)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 65)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 65)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 65)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 66
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARDP R 0.600006)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 62)
       (REP O 66)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 66)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 66)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 66)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 67
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARDP R 0.600006)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 63)
       (REP O 67)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 67)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 67)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 67)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 70
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 0.900009)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 70)
       (MID O 74)
       (BOT O 72)
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 70)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 70)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 70)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 71
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 0.900009)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 71)
       (MID O 75)
       (BOT O 73)
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 71)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 71)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 71)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 72
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 0.900009)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 70)
       (BOT O 72)
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 72)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 72)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 72)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 73
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 0.900009)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 71)
       (BOT O 73)
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 73)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 73)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 73)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 74
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 1.800018)
     (VARCHAR
       (REP O 77)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 74)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 74)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 74)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 75
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 1.800018)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 75)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 75)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 75)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 76
     (CHARWD R 1.777782)
     (CHARDP R 0.300003)
     (VARCHAR
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 76)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 76)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4444455)
       (SETCHAR O 76)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 77
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARDP R 0.600006)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 77)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 77)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 77)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 100
     (CHARWD R 1.750006)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 70)
       (BOT O 73)
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 100)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 100)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 100)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 101
     (CHARWD R 1.750006)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (VARCHAR
       (TOP O 71)
       (BOT O 72)
       (REP O 76)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 101)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 101)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 101)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 102
     (CHARWD R 1.750006)
     (CHARDP R 0.600006)
     (VARCHAR
       (REP O 102)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 102)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 102)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 102)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 103
     (CHARWD R 1.750006)
     (CHARDP R 0.600006)
     (VARCHAR
       (REP O 103)
       )
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 103)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 103)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.4375015)
       (SETCHAR O 103)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 104
     (CHARWD R 1.222226)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 34)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 104)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3055565)
       (SETCHAR O 104)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3055565)
       (SETCHAR O 104)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 105
     (CHARWD R 1.222226)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 35)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 105)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3055565)
       (SETCHAR O 105)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3055565)
       (SETCHAR O 105)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 120
     (CHARWD R 0.77778)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 0)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 2)
       (SETCHAR O 50)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 50)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 50)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 121
     (CHARWD R 0.77778)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 1)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 2)
       (SETCHAR O 51)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 51)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 51)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 122
     (CHARWD R 0.555558)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 2)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 2)
       (SETCHAR O 133)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.1388895)
       (SETCHAR O 133)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.1388895)
       (SETCHAR O 133)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 123
     (CHARWD R 0.555558)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 3)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 2)
       (SETCHAR O 135)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.1388895)
       (SETCHAR O 135)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.1388895)
       (SETCHAR O 135)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 124
     (CHARWD R 0.888892)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 4)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 142)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 142)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 142)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 125
     (CHARWD R 0.888892)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 5)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 143)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 143)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 143)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 126
     (CHARWD R 0.888892)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 6)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 144)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 144)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 144)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 127
     (CHARWD R 0.888892)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 7)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 145)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 145)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.222223)
       (SETCHAR O 145)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 130
     (CHARWD R 1.000004)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 10)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 146)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.250001)
       (SETCHAR O 146)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.250001)
       (SETCHAR O 146)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 131
     (CHARWD R 1.000004)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 11)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 147)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.250001)
       (SETCHAR O 147)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.250001)
       (SETCHAR O 147)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 132
     (CHARWD R 0.77778)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 12)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 150)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 150)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 150)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 133
     (CHARWD R 0.77778)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 13)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 151)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 151)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.194445)
       (SETCHAR O 151)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 134
     (CHARWD R 0.555558)
     (CHARHT R 0.75)
     (CHARDP R 0.25)
     (NEXTLARGER O 14)
     (MAP
       (SELECTFONT D 1)
       (SETCHAR O 152)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.1388895)
       (SETCHAR O 152)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.1388895)
       (SETCHAR O 152)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 150
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 24)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 150)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 150)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 150)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 151
     (CHARWD R 0.944448)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 25)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 151)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 151)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.236112)
       (SETCHAR O 151)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 152
     (CHARWD R 1.055562)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 26)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 152)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 152)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 152)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 153
     (CHARWD R 1.055562)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 27)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 153)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 153)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 153)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 154
     (CHARWD R 1.055562)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 30)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 154)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 154)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 154)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 155
     (CHARWD R 1.055562)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 31)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 155)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 155)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.2638905)
       (SETCHAR O 155)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 156
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 32)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 156)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 156)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 156)
       )
     )
   (CHARACTER O 157
     (CHARWD R 1.333338)
     (CHARHT R 0.039999)
     (CHARDP R 1.760019)
     (NEXTLARGER O 33)
     (MAP
       (SETCHAR O 157)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 157)
       (MOVELEFT R 0.3333345)
       (SETCHAR O 157)
       )
     )
   ```
3. Type the following at the shell prompt:

```
vptovf tripledelimiters10.vpl
```

This will generate two files called `tripledelimiters10.tfm`
and `tripledelimiters10.vf`, always in the same directory.

Save the following code into `tridelim.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}\relax % LaTeX2e is required!
\ProvidesPackage{tridelim}
                [2018/03/25 v0.01 (development)]
```

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tridelim}{\hyphenchar\font \m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tridelim}{m}{n}{<->tripledelimiters10}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{triplesymbols}{U}{tridelim}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lPparen}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"50}{triplesymbols}{"50}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rPparen}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"51}{triplesymbols}{"51}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBbrack}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"52}{triplesymbols}{"52}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBbrack}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"53}{triplesymbols}{"53}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lFfloor}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"54}{triplesymbols}{"54}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rFfloor}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"55}{triplesymbols}{"55}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lCceil}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"56}{triplesymbols}{"56}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rCceil}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"57}{triplesymbols}{"57}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBbrace}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"58}{triplesymbols}{"58}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBbrace}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"59}{triplesymbols}{"59}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lAangle}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"5A}{triplesymbols}{"5A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rAangle}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"5B}{triplesymbols}{"5B}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Vvert}{\mathord}
  {triplesymbols}{"5C}{triplesymbols}{"5C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lVvert}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"5C}{triplesymbols}{"5C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rVvert}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"5C}{triplesymbols}{"5C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Aarrowvert}{\mathord}
  {triplesymbols}{"3C}{triplesymbols}{"3C}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Bbracevert}{\mathord}
  {triplesymbols}{"3E}{triplesymbols}{"3E}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lGgroup}{\mathopen}
  {triplesymbols}{"3A}{triplesymbols}{"3A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rGgroup}{\mathclose}
  {triplesymbols}{"3B}{triplesymbols}{"3B}

Save the following code into `test.tex`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.
```

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tridelim}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\tripleparen}{\lPparen}{\rPparen}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplebrack}{\lBbrack}{\rBbrack}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplefloor}{\lFfloor}{\rFfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\tripleceil} {\lCceil} {\rCceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplebrace}{\lBbrace}{\rBbrace}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\tripleangle}{\lAangle}{\rAangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplevert} {\lVvert} {\rVvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplegroup}{\lGgroup}{\rGgroup}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplearrowvert}{\Aarrowvert}{\Aarrowvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\triplebracevert}{\Bbracevert}{\Bbracevert}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\triplebracket[3]{\lAangle}{\rAangle}
  {#1\,\delimsize\Vvert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\Vvert\,\mathopen{}#3}

\newcommand*{\testfraction}{\frac{a}{b}}
\newcommand*{\testbigfraction}{%
  \frac{\,\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}\,}{n!}%
}
\newcommand*{\testmatrix}{%
  \begin{matrix}%
    1&0&0&0\\%
    0&1&0&0\\%
    0&0&1&0\\%
    0&0&0&1%
  \end{matrix}%
}

\begin{document}

We begin with a simple formula: \( P\lPparen x\rPparen \).
Is it OK in sub-\slash superscripts too?  Let’s check:
\( Z^{P\lPparen x\rPparen} \), and \( 2^{Z_{P\lPparen x\rPparen}} \).
It works, but is suboptimal: indeed, compare it closely with
\( Z^{P(x)} \) and \( 2^{Z_{P(x)}} \).

Here are the normal sizes, in display:
\begin{align*}
  & x \tripleparen{y} z &
  & x \triplebrack{y} z &
  & x \triplefloor{y} z &
  & x \tripleceil {y} z &
  & x \triplebrace{y} z
  \\
  & x \tripleangle{y} z &
  & x \triplevert {y} z &
  & y \triplearrowvert*{x} z & % needs "\left" and "\right"
  & y \triplebracevert*{x} z   % needs "\left" and "\right"
\end{align*}

Here are the \verb|\big| sizes, in display:
\begin{align*}
  & x \tripleparen[\big]{y} z &
  & x \triplebrack[\big]{y} z &
  & x \triplefloor[\big]{y} z &
  & x \tripleceil [\big]{y} z &
  & x \triplebrace[\big]{y} z
  \\
  & x \tripleangle[\big]{y} z &
  & x \triplevert [\big]{y} z &
  & x \triplearrowvert[\big]{y} z &
  & x \triplebracevert[\big]{y} z
\end{align*}

Here are the \verb|\Big| sizes, in display:
\begin{align*}
  & x \tripleparen[\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplebrack[\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplefloor[\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \tripleceil [\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplebrace[\Big]{\testfraction} z
  \\
  & x \tripleangle[\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplegroup[\Big]{\testfraction} z & % not available at smaller sizes
  & x \triplevert [\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplearrowvert[\Big]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplebracevert[\Big]{\testfraction} z
\end{align*}

Here are the \verb|\bigg| sizes, in display:
\begin{align*}
  & x \tripleparen[\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplebrack[\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplefloor[\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \tripleceil [\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplebrace[\bigg]{\testfraction} z
  \\
  & x \tripleangle[\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplegroup[\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplevert [\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplearrowvert[\bigg]{\testfraction} z &
  & x \triplebracevert[\bigg]{\testfraction} z
\end{align*}

Here are the \verb|\Bigg| sizes, in display:
\begin{align*}
  & x \tripleparen[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \triplebrack[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \triplefloor[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \tripleceil [\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z
  \\
  & x \triplebrace[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \tripleangle[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \triplegroup[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z 
  \\
  & x \triplevert [\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \triplearrowvert[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z &
  & x \triplebracevert[\Bigg]{\testbigfraction} z
\end{align*}

And finally, the glorious auto-sizing delimiters, always in display:
\begin{align*}
  & x \tripleparen*{\testmatrix} z &
  & x \triplebrack*{\testmatrix} z &
  & x \triplefloor*{\testmatrix} z
  \\
  & x \tripleceil* {\testmatrix} z &
  & x \triplebrace*{\testmatrix} z &
  & x \triplegroup*{\testmatrix} z
  \\
  & x \triplevert* {\testmatrix} z &
  & x \triplearrowvert*{\testmatrix} z &
  & x \triplebracevert*{\testmatrix} z
\end{align*}

For the following example, cf.~p.~26 of the manual of the \textsf{mathtools}
package:
\( \triplebracket[\big]{B}{\sum_{k} f_k}{C} \).

\end{document}

Compiling `test.tex` should produce the following output:
[image: Output of the test]

Interested in the details?

Comment: This is impressive!

Comment: Note that the LaTeX code does not compile (I am using pdflatex); e.g., `(` and `)` should read `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: All your new symbols are beautiful.  There seem however to have some very small spacing issues in the triple bracket symbols.

Comment: I would suggest that your turn this into a package to put on CTAN.  This is very useful work.

Comment: @user94293: You are right, the code, as copied-and-pasted from this page, didn’t compile.  As I said, I was having problems with the 30000 character limit, so, in order to save some thousands keystrokes, I used `<PRE>` tags for the code excerpts instead of the four space indentation; unfortunately, inside `<PRE>` tags several backslashes were misinerpreted as starts of escape sequences, and disappeared from the visible code.  I hope I’ve now correctly “escaped from the escapes”: indeed, I tried to copy-and-paste the code from this page back to my editor, and it did compile.  Be forgiving… :-|

Comment: @user94293: The spacing between the repeated symbols is governed by the numbers that follow the `MOVELEFT` commands in the VPL file, and admittedly they need to be fine-tuned.  And yes, virtual font tricks tend to impresse people (:-), but they are not at all difficult to learn!  Try `texdoc vptovf`, and read sections 7 to 19 of the manual: they are only 8 pages…

Comment: @GuM great work....

Comment: +1 no one ever does what I suggest!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\tbr}[1]{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}{\mkern-5mu\delimsize\llbracket \mathopen{}#1 \mathclose{} \delimsize\rrbracket\mkern-5mu}`

You can find further information on page 26 in the [mathtools manual](ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#page=26). Basically `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{〈cmd〉}[〈num args〉]{〈left_delim〉}{〈right_delim〉}{〈body〉}` allows you to additionally specify a macro surrounded by the outer brackets. `\delimsize` gives the sizes of the outer brackets. `\mathopen{}` and `\mathclose{}` fix problem with the spacing which may occur (see this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610/157295) and the footnote on page 26 in the [mathtools manual](ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#page=26)).

**EDIT:** Here is what I have so far . There is a slight displacement with the smallest brackets and the starred version does not work. For better results I think one have to redefine `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,stmaryrd}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\dbr}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\tbr}[1]{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}{\nhphantom{$\delimsize\llbracket$}\delimsize\llbracket \mathopen{} #1 \mathclose{} \delimsize\rrbracket \nhphantom{$\delimsize\rrbracket$}}

\newcommand{\nhphantom}[1]{\sbox0{#1}\hspace{-0.751\wd0}}


\begin{document}

Double brackets:
\[
  \dbr{x} \quad \dbr[\big]{T^T}
\]

Triple brackets:
\[
  \tbr{x} \quad \tbr[\big]{T^T}
\]

\[
  {\llbracket}\nhphantom{$\llbracket$}{\textcolor{red}{\llbracket}} \quad
  {\big\llbracket}\nhphantom{$\big\llbracket$}{\textcolor{red}{\big\llbracket}} \quad
  {\Big\llbracket}\nhphantom{$\Big\llbracket$}{\textcolor{red}{\Big\llbracket}} \quad
  {\bigg\llbracket}\nhphantom{$\bigg\llbracket$}{\textcolor{red}{\bigg\llbracket}} \quad
  {\Bigg\llbracket}\nhphantom{$\Bigg\llbracket$}{\textcolor{red}{\Bigg\llbracket}}
\]


\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: With `\big`, it appears to be quadruple brackets rather than triple brackets.

Comment: @user94293 Sorry, I have not noticed before. I have edited the post now. Now it is right.

Comment: It is right with `\big` but not without (it appears as a double bracket)

Comment: @user94293 Sorry, now it is better.

Comment: `\hspace{-0.751\dimexpr\the\wd0 \relax}` is a long way to get the same as `\hspace{-0.751\wd0}`.